# Why I can access class that is defined outside of namespace?

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I was wondering Why I can access class when I defined it outside of namespace scope?

I am not very familiar with namespaces, I am just learning, but I thought that namespace should like wrap all my classes to one 'box' and they can access each other just inside that 'box' (scope).

Code example:

```
class Point
{
    public int X;
}

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point p = new Point();
            p.X = 50;
            Console.WriteLine(p.X);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Are you `import` the namespace where _Point_ class resides?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu: The `Point` class isn't in a namespace. That's the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Namespaces have *nothing* to do with access. It's important to differentiate between namespaces and assemblies - they're often closely related, in that types in a namespace `Foo.Bar` would be likely to be in assembly `Foo.Bar.dll`, but that's a convention - it's not something the compiler or language cares about.

A namespace is primarily "a space in which names have to be unique". In other words, while it's fine to have two types called `Point` in different namespaces, you can't have two types called `Point` in the *same* namespace. Indeed, the primary reason for namespaces existing (IMO) is so that we *don't* all have to use completely unique names across every piece of .NET code in the world.

You can use your `Point` class which is implicitly `internal` so long as it's declared within the same assembly. If it's in the global namespace (i.e. not declared in a namespace at all) then you don't need any `using` directives to refer to it - the purpose of a `using` directive is to allow you to refer to members of a different namespace just by their short name.

So if you have:

```
namespace Foo.Bar
{
    public class Baz {}
}
```

then you could access that as either:

```
namespace Other
{
    class Test
    {
        Foo.Bar.Baz baz = new Foo.Bar.Baz();
    }
}
```

or

```
// Allow anything in namespace Foo.Bar to be accessed by its
// short name
using Foo.Bar;

namespace Other
{
    class Test
    {
        Baz baz = new Baz();
    }
}
```

If the type is defined in the "global" namespace, then you just don't need the `using` directive. From the C# 5 language specification section 3.8 (namespace and type names) where it's describing the type name lookup procedure:

> If the previous steps were unsuccessful then, for each namespace N, starting with the namespace in which the namespace-or-type-name occurs, continuing with each enclosing namespace (if any), and ending with the global namespace, the following steps are evaluated until an entity is located

So in your case, looking for `Point` from your `Main` method, first `ConsoleApplication12` would be checked for a `Point` type, then the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

To access class, outside namespace, your class should be public

```
public class Point
```

and in your namespace, where you want to see this class, you need to add namespace in top of usings

```
using mynamespace.external;
```

Than you can access your class

Comment: It doesn't need to be public. It can be internal (the default) so long as the accessing code is in the same assembly.

Comment: That sounds good, but I was wondering why my code works even if I didn't do this. I just defined class outside of my Namespace and I can still create object of that class in inside of my Namespace

Comment: @JakubGause: What's unclear to me is why you think it *shouldn't* work. Presumably you're used to using types from other namespaces... this is just the global namespace. Why did you expect it to fail?

Comment: sorry, my mistake, class Point is in the same file, as I now understood.  So it will work. I assumed, it is in different file with different namespace. Yes I usually work with many namespaces and do not go out of them.